# Smallest TSP instance with unknown optimal solution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

What is smallest Traveling Salesman Problem instance that has practical or theoretical relevance but whose optimal solution isn't known?

Comment: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/data/index.html